# Captcha Popup when asked

Tags: c#, https, automation

I want to make a gui-less automation software but when the site asks for a captcha after hitting a submit button, to make a popup window possibly using a WebClient, solving it manually, then closing when its done. Is that possible to do with any libraries?

Comment: You can search for a captcha solver like https://www.opensourceagenda.com/tags/captcha-solving. I use https://anti-captcha.com that is not free but cheap and works nice (not solve always but almost always)

Comment: It's not like a normal captcha but a custom one, that's why I need for a popup since it's fairly new. I'll check out the site you gave me. THanks

Comment: You always can use selenium or a browser control like CefSharp to automate that, but it has some amount of work.

Comment: Do you know any projects that have done this or something similar?

Comment: You can find lots of CefSharp examples, like in https://cefsharp.github.io, https://csharp.hotexamples.com/es/examples/CefSharp.WinForms/ChromiumWebBrowser/-/php-chromiumwebbrowser-class-examples.html, https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/173/how-to-use-cefsharp-chromium-embedded-framework-csharp-in-a-winforms-application...